# Flutter onTap stopped working and null error

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

i'm getting null error in flutter button stopped working after added if statement inside the ontap here is my flutter code error `Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: '<Unexpected Null Value>'`
here is my button code

```
import 'package:efood_multivendor/controller/product_controller.dart';
import 'package:efood_multivendor/util/dimensions.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get_core/src/get_main.dart';
import 'package:get/get_instance/src/extension_instance.dart';
import 'package:get/get_utils/src/extensions/internacionalization.dart';

import 'custom_snackbar.dart';

class QuantityButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isIncrement;
  final Function onTap;
  final int quantity;
  final int stock;
  QuantityButton(
      {@required this.isIncrement,
      @required this.onTap,
      @required this.quantity,
      @required this.stock});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onTap({
      if(quantity < stock) {
      Get.find()<ProductController>(context, listen: false).setQuantity(true);
      } else {
      showCustomSnackBar('out_of_stock'.tr);
      }

      }),
      child: Container(
        height: 22,
        width: 22,
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Dimensions.PADDING_SIZE_SMALL),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          border: Border.all(
              width: 1,
              color: isIncrement
                  ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
                  : Theme.of(context).disabledColor),
          color: isIncrement
              ? Theme.of(context).primaryColor
              : Theme.of(context).disabledColor.withOpacity(0.2),
       
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

please help me o solve this problem without removing onTap : onTap function

Answer (score 0):

The error is originating from the value you are providing to the onTap parameter of the InkwWell widget,
the onTap parameter is expecting a `{void Function()?}` and what you are providing is not the right type.
What you are doing is calling the onTap of the widget with a parameter of type Set, instead of providing the function itself.
The solution would be either to pass widget's onTap directly to the InkWell onTap like this

```
InkWell(
      onTap: onTap,
```

or if you wanna call the onTap with parameters you can use a lambda function like this :

```
InkWell(
      onTap: () => onTap(param1: value1, param2: value2),
```

These two solutions should work but what I see here, is that you are trying to define a logic when calling the onTap, which is not correct. the widget's onTap logic should be defined when creating the QuantityButton  class like the following :

```
QuantityButton(
  onTap : () {
    if(quantity < stock) {
      Get.find()<ProductController>(context, listen: false).setQuantity(true);
     } else {
      showCustomSnackBar('out_of_stock'.tr);
      }
  }, rest of the parameters...);
```

Comment: how i can define if function now i have tried both but didn't work

Comment: Ok, so in the Inkwell widget, give the onTap parameter the onTap property directly, like the first code sample in the answer, and in the QuantityButton instantiation, write the third code simple in the answer adding the left out paramters.

Comment: sorry to ask again can you show in code like how to mention it i have tried it but not working

Comment: replace the `onTap({
      if(quantity < stock) {
      Get.find()<ProductController>(context, listen: false).setQuantity(true);
      } else {
      showCustomSnackBar('out_of_stock'.tr);
      }

      }),` with `onTap` only.

Comment: And in the code where you are creating the QuantityButton, that should look like this `QuantityButton(some parameters here)` give the onTap parameter a value like the following `QuantityButton(onTap: (){
      if(quantity < stock) {
      Get.find()<ProductController>(context, listen: false).setQuantity(true);
      } else {
      showCustomSnackBar('out_of_stock'.tr);
      }

      }, the rest of your parameters here);`

Comment: this is how you mentioned right ? ```class QuantityButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isIncrement;
  final Function onTap;
  final int quantity;
  final int stock;
  QuantityButton(
      this.isIncrement,
      this.onTap,
      this.quantity,
      this.stock);

  QuantityButton(
  onTap: (){ 
    if(quantity < stock) 
    {Get.find()<ProductController>(context, listen: false).setQuantity(true);       
    } else {
      showCustomSnackBar('out_of_stock'.tr);}},);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onTap,```

Comment: i' getting error on this error is ```the default value of an optional parameter must be constant```

Comment: and tried this ```onTap: () => onTap(stock <= quantity ? 'out_of_stock'.tr :Get.back()),``` and getting unexpected null value

Comment: `onTap: () => (stock <= quantity ? 'out_of_stock'.tr :Get.back())` try this instead (removing the onTap)

Comment: no still getting unexpected null value error

Comment: Please refer to the documentation on function and function parameters in dart/flutter. I can't help you more with that, with the information provided.

Comment: Would you provide the code that's calling QuantityButton?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237679/discussion-between-crazymhegde-and-abdelkrim-bournane).

Comment: ```QuantityButton(
onTap: () => productController.setQuantity(true),
isIncrement: true, quantity: quantity, stock: stock,
),```